# React clone vs object.assign

Tags: reactjs

So in my setState method i have following code that works fine.

```
onDropoffTimeChange(event) {
  event.persist();
  this.setState((currentState) => {
    const searchParams = currentState.searchParams.clone();
    searchParams.dropoffTime = event.target.value;
    return { searchParams };
  });
}
```

Clone is a method i put inside SearchParams class like following:

```
class SearchParams {
  constructor(
    aDropoffTime,
  ) {
    this.dropoffTime = aDropoffTime;
  }

  clone() {
    return new SearchParams(
      this.dropoffTime,
    );
  }
}
```

Now it was my understanding that object.assign would do the same thing? In other words i would like to get rid of my clone method and use following but it does not update the state?

```
onDropoffTimeChange(event) {
  event.persist();
  this.setState((currentState) => {
    const searchParams = Object.assign({}, currentState.searchParams);
    searchParams.dropoffTime = event.target.value;
    return { searchParams };
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you try `(currentState) => Object.assign({}, { dropoffTime: event.target.value });`

Comment: It's not updating because of Reacts shallow comparison algorithm when determining whether a component needs to be updated. Doing as Paveloosha suggested is one way to fix your problem as spreading the existing state in to a variable will move the variable to different memory blocks and thus be recognized in React as having been updated.

Comment: This did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use '...' operators to get rid of 'clone' method if you are using ES-6.

```
    this.setState((currentState) => {
       return {
         searchParams: {
           ...currentState.searchParams,
           dropoffTime: event.target.value,
        }
       };
    });
```

Comment: Edited: Missed one level earlier. Now you can try.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Object spread method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy an iterable.

If dropoffTime is part of your searchParams object you will need to spread the currentState.searchParams inside of the searchParams object.

```
this.setState((currentState) => {
   return {
     searchParams: {
       ...currentState.searchParams,
       dropoffTime: event.target.value
     }
   };
});
```